# implement change value on drag (like you do in Photoshop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am brainstorming on how to change value of a text on drag over. Basically, you drag to the left, value decreased. You drag to the right -> value increases.

This functionality is implemented in Adobe Products. Check this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/20dXG.png

Note that on drag only the value changes. I do not move the element in any way so JQuery UI draggable doesn't seem to be an option.

This is the starter(almost empty) template:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owadRe

```
<div class="drag">123</div>

.drag{
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

How would you create such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plugins that do this if you Google it, but really it's just a matter of constantly getting the mouse's x position in relation to the clicked element then updating the value by that distance (or some transformation of that distance).

Below is a pretty unrefined and quick example using jquery.

```js
$(".drag").on('mousedown', e => {
  // get initial value
  let val = parseInt($('.drag').text());
  $('body, .drag').toggleClass('dragging');
  // check mousemove
  $('body').on('mousemove', e => {
    let xinit = $('.drag').offset().left; // element x position
    let xfin = e.pageX; // mouse x position
    let dVal = Math.floor(val + (xfin - xinit));
    $('.drag').text(dVal);
  });
  // remove mousemove when done clicking
  $('body').on('mouseup', e => {
    $('body, .drag').toggleClass('dragging');
    $('body').off('mousemove');
  })
})
```

```css
body, html{
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  display : flex;
  align-items : center;
  justify-content : center;
  background-color : yellow;
}
body.dragging{
  cursor : ew-resize;
}
.drag {
  cursor: ew-resize;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="drag">123</div>
</body>
```